# convert condition into function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a function to validate data from a form:

```
var step1_validation = function(){
            var err = 0;
            if($('#one').val() == '0'){
               $('#one').parent().parent().find('.form-error').html("display error for one.");
                err++;
            }
            if($('#other').val() == '0'){
                $('#other').parent().parent().find('.form-error').html("display error for other.");
                err++;
            }
        if($('#eda').val() == ''){
                $('#eda').parent().parent().find('.form-error').html("display error for one eda.");
                err++;
            }

            if(err == 0){
                //do something
            }else{
                //do other stuff               
            }
        };
```

As there are several inputs I would like to validate How can I make a function to verify input is 0 or empty string, and call it inside my function?

```
if($('#id').val() == '0'){
   $('#id').parent().parent().find('.form-error').html("display message.");
   err++;
}

or 

if($('#id').val() == ''){
   $('#id').parent().parent().find('.form-error').html("display message.");
   err++;
}
```

Comment: add your whole code in document.ready ? i guess i am not taking your question wrong ? am i

Comment: why in quotes `'0'` ?????

Comment: that code is inside `$(document).ready(function() { } `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
var step1_validation = function () {
    var err = 0;
    err += validateInput('one', 'display error for one.');
    err += validateInput('other', 'display error for other.');
    err += validateInput('eda', 'display error for eda.');

    if (err == 0) {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do other stuff               
    }
};

function validateInput(id, errorMessage) {
    var obj = $('#' + id);
    if (obj.val() == '0' || obj.val() == ''){
       obj.parent().parent().find('.form-error').html(errorMessage);
       return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to use the passed it instead of 'id'

Comment: but how to tell if I am waiting for 0, or empty string, Should I add a flag to indicate a flow depending on 0 or string?

Comment: @cMinor why do you need to know outside the function?